# How to scale svg within bootstrap panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

This svg works as expected, however, when resizing using viewBox, my result has been less than optimal. The svg seems to be a layer over the top of the div I am trying to have it inside of. The goal is to have several gauges within these bootstrap panels, but I have not got past the first...

Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/3quWHAs1EpMQAv7P4dZC?p=preview

Not sure if I have the d3 js incorrect, or the bootstrap incorrect, or a combination of both..

```
var svg = d3.select( "#g1" )
  .append( "svg" )
  .classed("svg-container", true)
  //responsive SVG needs these 2 attributes and no width and height attr
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 400 400")
  // class to make it responsive
  .attr('class', 'svg-content-responsive');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was the `position: absolute;` in your class .svg-content-responsive.

Removed it and now your svg will be displayed in your first Panel.

https://plnkr.co/edit/yWxphIYjfcLB0ReYxS3a?p=preview